# Фильтрация массива в JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, фильтрация

Есть два массива:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'arr 1 name 1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'arr 1 name 2'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'arr 1 name 3'
}];

const arr2 = [{
  id: '3',
  name: 'arr 2 name 3'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'arr 2 name 4'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'arr 2 name 5'
}];

const arr3 = arr1.filter((el) => el.id === arr2.map((el) => el.id));

console.log(arr3);
```

Нужно отфильтровать из `arr1` только те объекты, которые совпадают по `id` с `arr2`. И результат этой фильтрации положить в `arr3`. Можно это как-то сделать, желательно без цикла? В данном примере должно вывести только `id: '3'`, т.к. он совпадает. Но почему-то он его туда не включает...

Comment: а чем цикл не угодил?

Comment: `map` возвращает массив, а вы его с `id` сравниваете

Comment: @ThisMan Ищу самый короткий вариант реализации... У меня что-то и так циклов много, стараюсь их в самых крайних случаях использовать

Comment: а вы знаете, что `map` это по сути тот же цикл?

Comment: @ThisMan ну я имею ввиду хотелось бы одной строкой все записать в arr3, цикл больше кода даёт

Comment: Может имеет смысл пересмотреть логику скрипта и прибегнуть к помощи `Set` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/set

Comment: @Hit-or-miss, это я здесь привел небольшой кусочек с проблемой (так скрипт достаточно большой и он связан с многим другим), логику менять будет проблематично и долго... К тому же я ещё начинающий, переписывать буду долго((( Но всё равно, спасибо за помощь! Я про Set знал, но не думал, что его можно применить как-то в моём случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитать про `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'arr 1 name 1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'arr 1 name 2'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'arr 1 name 3'
}];

const arr2 = [{
  id: '3',
  name: 'arr 2 name 3'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'arr 2 name 4'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'arr 2 name 5'
}];

// Используем some вместо map
const arr3 = arr1.filter((el) => arr2.some((el2) => el2.id === el.id));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Ух ты, даже не знал, что есть такое! Спасибо большущее!!! Вы сэкономили мне кучу времени, обязательно почитаю про него.